# Implementation of Naive string matching algorithm

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, search

I found a very useful code on Naive string algorithm which was written in python but it doesn't seem to be running what is the problem?

```
def naive(p, t):
occurrences = []
for i in range(len(t) - len(p) + 1):  # loop over alignments
    match = True
    for j in range(len(p)):           # loop over characters
        if t[i+j] != p[j]:            # compare characters
            match = False             # mismatch; reject alignment
            break                     #goes back to the outer loop and start the next step of looping in the alignment
    if match:                         #if match remained true 
      occurrences.append(i)           # all chars matched; record
return occurrences
```

`naive("asge","asgefjlso")` #to run #but it doesn't run and doesn't show anything

can someone also please explain for me what does if t[i+j] != p[j] mean and do ?

Comment: can you post sample input and expected output

Comment: "

I found a very useful code on Naive string algorithm which was written in python but it doesn't seem to be running" -- if it isn't running in what sense it useful? That is like saying "I found a very useful car but I can't get it to drive." Also, your question isn't clear. Are you asking what `!=` means in Python? If that is your question, you could benefit from working through a basic tutorial.

Comment: my question is  about this part if t[i+j] , what does i+j  indicate in an inner loop ?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you have executed the code in the same format as attached above then it will not run because of indentation problem , correct code with proper indentation is as follows

```
def naive(p, t):
    occurrences = []
    for i in range(len(t) - len(p) + 1):  # loop over alignments
        match = True
        for j in range(len(p)):             # loop over characters
            if t[i+j] != p[j]:                # compare characters
                match = False                  # mismatch; reject alignment
                break                          #goes back to the outer loop 
                                               # and start the 
                                          #next 
                                         #step of looping in the alignment
    if match:                             #if match remained true 
        occurrences.append(i)               # all chars matched; record
    return occurrences
```

Comment: @Shehab can you please explain what type of error are you getting?

Comment: Not any single error, it compiles successfully but doesn't show a result

Comment: @Shehab actually when you are calling the function it is returning you the occurrences , you have to print the occurrences in order to see the output , use    print(naive("asge","asgefjlso"))

Comment: if t[i+j] for this part , what does i+j  indicate ?

Comment: @Shehab see you compare the characters of string t with string p. you are running a for loop (j) from 0 to len(p)-1. in that loop you first check whether t[i] matches with p[j] (j=0) i.e. first character , if it matches then you increment j checking whether each successive element of p i.e. p[j] matches with t[i+j]. we are just moving forward in both strings checking for occurrence of same character in both. if in case we found mismatch we break the loop